# About design support library

Tags: android

By adding design support library, we can bring the TextInputLayout animation in lower versions too, den what is the use of lollipop version in this case?

Comment: lollipop version have more feature. if you dot want no need to use that feature in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has come up with variety of new features in lollipop and support library is for reduce developer efforts to get stuffs done.

And they too provide support to older device for same look and feel.

So day by day they are improving their feature and also giving backward support.